# connect with Windows SSL server through iOS app using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In my server i have implemented SSL certificate and connected through my android app using retrofit just by passing URL and parameter.
now i am developing iOS version of the app using Alamofire to connect with same API but getting SSL error.

[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2866 [boringssl_session_handshake_continue] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library
[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_handshake_error_print: line 2805 boringssl ctx 0x7fcff052b0d0: 140531107629232:error:100000f0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-109.50.14/ssl/handshake_client.c:970:
[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_os_status: line 4304 SSL_AD_PROTOCOL_VERSION

TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x6000001708c0]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802)
 NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
 Task <76674C26-EED0-41DE-BB94-A0FF9F8F22A0>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])

My code in swift 4 to connect with server

Alamofire.request("https://url/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON { response in
                    if response.result.isSuccess{
                        print(“success”)
                    }
                    else {
                        print ("Error  (String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    }

is there anything additional need to be done to connect iOS with network.
I have gone through various questions already posted by various users but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 9.0 or later have built in support for ATS which is enabled by default. Alamofire works with https// but for that NSAllowsArbitraryLoads need to be defined in info.plist by adding NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=YES

However disabling ATS is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with the server configuration which is not accepted by the ATS in iOS. The iOS client is not able to create a handshake with the server. To check the validity go to https://www.ssllabs.com. Add your server (eg www.google.com) and run the test. Once the server test completes go forth and check the following fields.

[image]

If this one doesnt shows as in the picture (green and not red) then the app cannot connect to the server. You will have to configure the server with the correct configuration for ATS. This link gives more details about it. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Attaching a screenshot of the relevant part.[image]

The main features being forward secrecy, TLS 1.2, the required symmetric cipher an required server certificate. Hope this is what you are looking for. Do let me know if it is. :)

NB: A quick way to check whether it is the correct reason for your problem is to run the application in a iOS 7 simulator. It should connect and no error should happen as iOS 7 doesnt have ATS.

Comment: to disable ATS even i used NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in .plist file but of no use.

Comment: Make your request http:// instead of https://, then NSAllowsArbitraryLoads will work. Otherwise it won't. Cheers.

Comment: I need to use https only can't use http.